# Link between certain aspects of basic behavioural traits

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, psychology

Is there a correlation in certain aspects of human traits,whether it is gene related.

People from dominating countries during the early 1800s invading into other nations.

For e.g:Portuguese,British people have a higher degree of self respect and sense of command as compared to the invaded country population.These 'invaded country, people collectively develop a sense of inferiority.And it is passed through the years.

Thus is it likely for people in the present age to show similar traits due to genes?

Comment: So there's been lots of research in regards to genetics and behaviour. Could you specify what aspects of behaviour you are interested in?

Comment: hey Seanny123, maybe give some examples of connections that have been found between genetics and behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  It's possible that behavioural traits are genetic to some extent, but it's impossible to separate that from the environmental influences enough to link to specific events such as invading other countries.  Also, usually invaders stayed to colonize the country they invaded so that there was a mixing of the genes of invaded and invaders.  So even if there were links between genetics and likelihood to invade, you couldn't make the connection now between historical events and the behavioural traits of the current generation.